# Can static array indices be used with opaque struct types?

Tags: c, static, c99, opaque-types

There is an opaque structure that I want to rewrite a function for:

```
// Set.h
typedef struct Set Set;

void Set_Function(Set* self);
```

**I would like to modify the function to indicate to the developer that a pointer equal to `(void*) 0` is not permitted:**

```
void Set_Function(Set self[static 1]);
```

**However, Clang complains that I have an incomplete array type.**

**Is this functionality possible**, or do I have to keep the original function declaration and manually check for `(void*) 0` pointers?

**Edit for the people in the comments:**

Modern C by Jens Gustedt suggests the following on page 204:

> Functions that receive pointers should use array syntax and distinguish different cases:

> - A pointer to a single object of the type – These functions should use the static 1 notation and thus indicate that they expect a pointer that is non-null:
>   `void func ( double a[ static 1]) ;`

> - A pointer to a collection of objects of known number – These functions should use the static N notation and thus indicate that they expect a pointer that points to at least that number of elements:
>   `void func ( double a[ static 7]) ;`

> - A pointer to a collection of objects of unknown number – These functions
>   should use the VLA notation:
>   `void func ( size_t n, double a[n]) ;`

> - A pointer to a single object of the type or a null pointer – Such a function must guarantee that even when it receives a null pointer, the execution remains in a defined state:
>   `void func ( double * a) ;`

> Compiler builders only start to implement checks for these cases, so your compiler probably will not yet detect such errors. Nevertheless, writing these down and make them clear for yourself will help you to avoid out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: That `static` keyword is part of the array declarator, and, looking at the declaration grammar, there is no way to weasel it into a pointer declarator. It is not well-enforced anyway; if you are passing a pointer directly to the routine, rather than an array, [Clang does not detect it even if it is obvious](https://godbolt.org/z/av4Y459WW), let alone if the code is convoluted. That use of `static` is mostly to enable optimizations in the called routine, not to provide checking in calling routines.

Comment: `free(NULL)` is safe and a no-op.

Comment: Is this defined in the standard, in every implementation ?

Comment: @dbush Right, but dereferencing a NULL pointer in the implementation is not safe. I may be able to free Set, but there is no such guarantee if Set contains other memory that is dynamically allocated.

Comment: @Biggs If the parameter is null, just `return`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understand that the use of static here is for optimization purposes and may not statically prevent the use of a NULL pointer. The use of static here should let the developer know not to provide a NULL pointer.

Comment: Clang has two (extension) keywords `_Nonnull` and `_Nullable` that can be used to document whether NULL is allowed for the pointer arguments to a function. You should probably hide those behind some conditional preprocessor statements if portability is a concern.

Comment: Whatever you indicate to the programmer will not be enforced by the compiler, so just write a comment.

Comment: @n.m. Clang at least enforces direct invocations of the function with a NULL argument.

Comment: So you are safe in one totally unrealistic case.

Comment: If you accept an array of a known size, then you can't pass a pointer, because the compiler can't, in the general case, know if that pointer is NULL or not, so it can't say "yep, pointer points to N elements". Just add a comment and an input check.

Answer (score -1):

There are few points to considers:

- Making input parameter as array ussually do as: `void Set_Delete(Set self[]);`. But this will have some limit in usage in future.
- checking input is the normal approach that everyone do.